# DataContextChanged raised multiple times with the same argument

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10

I'm implementing the new compiled binding in my UWP application and I'm having a problem. As suggested in other questions here on SO, I've added this code to my `UserControl(s)` I'm using as my `DataTemplate(s)`:

```
this.DataContextChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.NewValue != null) this.Bindings.Update();
}
```

In XAML I'm defining my data template as usual (simplified XAML):

```
<ListView>
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="dataModels:MyItemModel">
            <templates:MyDataTemplate/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The whole thing **does work**, but I noticed that the `DataContextChanged` event was getting raised multiple times with the same value. In order not to waste CPU time by calling `Bindings.Update()` multiple times when it wasn't necessary (since the `ViewModel` was the same), I've added this (ugly) workaround:

```
public MyUserControl()
{
this.InitializeComponent();
this.DataContextChanged += (s, e) =>
    {
        // Check both for null and for repeated calls
        if (e.NewValue != null && e.NewValue != _LastDataContext)
        {
            _LastDataContext = e.NewValue;
            this.Bindings.Update();
        }
    };
}

// Private field to skip repeated calls of Bindings.Update()
private object _LastDataContext;
```

Now, this works as well, but I'm *sure* there is a better way to fix this and to prevent the `DataContextChanged` event from being called multiple times when it's not necessary?

Do you have any suggestions? Than you for your help!

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're trying to do -- `x:Bind` doesn't use `DataContext`, but binds to the object itself (the `UserControl` in your case). Unless you `x:Bind` to the `DataContext` or something?

Comment: @PetterHesselberg I'm using a UserControl as my DataTemplate, I have a ViewModel property in the control code-behind that type casts the DataContext, the x:Bind use that property as their source. I need that Bindings.Update() call to refresh the bindings the first time or when the ListView virtualization reuses the same control instances with different data items

Comment: Got it. I don't know why `DataContextChanged` is invoked multiple times, though -- all I can suggest is you set a breakpoint and try to figure out what triggers it...

Comment: @PetterHesselberg I'm not sure how to do that, I mean, where to put the breakpoint, since it's the ListView that creates the template instances and does all the job. I only see that event getting raised with the same DataContext. I guess my workaround des save some CPU, but it looks ugly. Isn't it normal for that even to get called multiple times? I mean, maybe I got it wrong and this is the expected behavior when dealing with custom UserControls in DataTemplates..

Comment: To start with, I'd try a breakpoint in your `DataContextChanged` handler.

Comment: @PetterHesselberg Oh, well I've already done that, ad well as using Debug.WriteLine, that's how I realized the handler was getting called multiple times in the first place. The argument is always the same and I wouldn't know how to figure out what caused that even to be raised more than a single time for a given DataContext value though

Comment: Years later I am seeing exactly the same thing.   When I tried to debug this and step out of the event `DataContextChanged` handler back to the invoking code, it just took me right back into the same handler a second time.  (And, of course, I made sure I was only subscribing to `DataContextChanged` once.  It still got invoked twice)

Comment: And I just figured it out.  I had both a manual event subscription in the constructor of the control as well as one declared in XAML pointing to the same handler.    I'm guessing that's why the OP saw this as well.  Toolate to help him, maybe but could help the next person who comes along.  If this happens to you, look to see if your XAML and your code are doing the same subscription.